# Stability of a three-dimensional system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, jacobian

when I consider the three-dimensional ODE system such as
$$
\dot{x} = \frac{25}{(1+y^2)(1+z^2)} - x\\
\dot{y} = \frac{25}{(1+x^2)(1+z^2)} - y\\
\dot{z} = \frac{5}{1+(x+y)^2} - z
$$
There is an equilibrium state $$(2.78581, 2.78581, 0.15604).$$ When I substitute this equilibrium point into the corresponding Jacobian matrix. The eigenvalues at this equilibrium point are
$$
[-2.82226, -0.949452, 0.771709]
$$
Since there is a positive eigenvalue, this equilibrium should be defined as an unstable state. However, when I simulated this system in MATLAB, the simulation results show that this equilibrium state seems like a stable state. I was wondering how this thing happens? Is there anything I misunderstood?

Comment: I get four real solutions  and the one you show is not one of them. Are you sure that critical point is correct?

Comment: @Moo I found all critical points by Mathematica, and there are totally three real solutions and 14 complex solutions.

Comment: I am assuming a typo: the third equation should have $-z$ instead of $-x$.

Comment: @maxmilgram you are right! Sorry for the typo! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Moo I had a typo with my first version. Now, the typo is corrected. Sorry for that

Comment: Did you try to start with something that is specifically in the eingenspace of the unstable eigenvector?

Comment: @maxmilgram Nope, would you mind give a hint about this?

Comment: Well to test your numerical scheme you can use a specific starting point, namely the equilibrium state + $\varepsilon v_3$, where $\varepsilon$ is a small number and $v_3$ is the eigenvector to the positive eigenvalue.

Comment: @maxmilgram This is the eigenvector to the positive eigenvalue [0.707107, -0.707107, 3.89451*10^-18]. I followed your way to test my numerical scheme with eps = 0.001, and the story is the system left the equilibrium state. Thus, I think there is no enough neighbourhood around the equilibrium state I showed, which means it is unstable. But I got a question, why the numerical result shows that the system can stay at this unstable state? Would you mind give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wrap up of the comments under the OP:

Your understanding of the eigenvalues is correct. Since we know that your numerical scheme indeed shows the correct behaviour for non-attractive eigenvector the numerics reflect the expected behaviour.

Now if you are on the equilibirium state and (numerical) pertubations occur only in the direction of the two stable eigenvectors, you stay at the equilibrium. If you get a pertubation in direction of the unstable eigenvector you should eventually(!) move away from it. Depending on the numerical scheme there might be the possibility of some artificial damping.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification！